# Readmission of patient through 30 days after first discharge (total 31 days)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below sample data in one of my table and I want to find **"If the discharge is followed by a readmission through 30 days after first discharge (total 31 days), use the admit date from the first admission and the discharge date from the last discharge"**.

```
PatientId ClaimId   Admit Date  Discharge Date
A001    110001  12/20/2019  1/17/2020
A001    110002  4/30/2020   4/30/2020
A001    110003  4/18/2020   4/30/2020
A001    110004  5/1/2020    5/5/2020
A001    110005  5/8/2020    5/27/2020
A001    110006  8/22/2020   9/20/2020
A001    110007  9/2/2020    9/5/2020
A001    110008  9/21/2020   10/20/2020
A001    110009  10/21/2020  11/19/2020
A001    110010  9/2/2020    9/5/2020
```

I tried this way but I can get only min of admit date. Not sure how to find Max of discharge date through 30 days after first discharge. Appreciate help.

```
SELECT A.PatientId,
       A.Discharge_Date, 
Min(B.Admit_Date) AS MinOfadmitDate, 
DATEDIFF(dd,A.Discharge_Date,Min(B.Admit_Date)) AS Day_span
FROM Table1 A 
INNER JOIN Table1 AS B ON A.PatientId = B.PatientId
WHERE B.Admit_Date > A.Discharge_Date
GROUP BY A.PatientId, A.Discharge_Date
HAVING DATEDIFF(dd,A.Discharge_Date, Min(B.Admit_Date))<=30
```

Comment: In this example can you share the expected results

Comment: ... and provide this sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts - the picture is not useful.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You've tagged MySQL and SQL Server - which is it?

Comment: @Akina, replaced pic with data. Can you help now?

Comment: *replaced pic with data* I see neither CREATE TABLE statement nor INSERT INTO statement.

Comment: @Akina - I added select statement which I tried

Answer (score 0):

> Can any one help to find min of admit date and max of discharge date
> through 30 days after first discharge?

I think you can use the analytical function to find the first discharge date and then use aggregate function to find `min` and `max` from 30 days as follows:

```
select t.patientid, 
       min(admit_date) as min_Admit_date, 
       max(discharge_date) as max_discharge_date 
  from (select t.*, 
               min(discharge_date) over (partition by patientid) as min_d_date
         from your_table t) t
 where dateadd(d,30,min_d_date) > admit_date
```

Comment: this is resulting only 1st line

Comment: Then what is expected result?